# Sum the column values in one dimensional list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sum

I have the following list, which goes from 1 to 1000. Here I have 29 columns and in each list I have one row (one dimensional list)

Here is my sample `r` code.

```
data = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=29000)
va1 = c(seq(1, 29000, by = 28))
DF21 <- mapply(function(a, b) DF[a:b, ], va, c(va[-1], nrow(DF)),
              SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
DF21
```

[image]

I use the `do.call(rbind,lapply(DF2, colSums))` to compute the column sum. But I am getting an error message as "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions"

How to sum columns in each list here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi score, please edit your question to make it a minimum reproducible example (that is, one that we can cut and paste your data and your code into our own R sessions to reproduce the error, and demonstrate a solution). Thanks :)

Comment: This `lapply(DF2, sum)` gives the sum of rows.

Comment: @李哲源 I am getting the same error message again. "Error in rowSums(simplify2array(DF2)) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you posted does not construct a list. It fails in the 3rd statement because 'va' does not exist.

The following code will help you to sum columns. It shows how to turn a vector to a matrix, sum the matrix columns, turn matrix to a list, return it back to and matrix.

```
data = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=29000) # reusing your first line
mat <- matrix(data,nrow=1000,ncol=29) # constructing a 1000* by 29 matrix
colsum <- apply(mat,2,sum) # This sums the columns
l <- split(mat, 1:1000) # produce a list that looks like what you posted
mat2<-matrix(unlist(l),nrow=1000,ncol=29) # turn the list back to a matrix
colsum2 <- apply(mat,2,sum) # sum the columns again :-)
```